# Where's hashHistory in React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use a router for my React application. I tried something I'd been using a while back, but can't seem to get it going.  Has `hashHistory` been removed/reformatted in React Router v4?

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={MainContainer} />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use a [`HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter). They got rid of individual histories such as `browserHistory` and `hashHistory` and instead replaced them with `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` components respectively in React Router v4:

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<HashRouter>
  …
</HashRouter>
```

Note that `HashRouter` comes from *`react-router-dom`, not the core `react-router` package*.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!