# import browserHistory from react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend

i'm trying to import browserHistory but i get error something like this.

```
 ./src/App.js
  Attempted import error: 'browserHistory' is not exported from 'react- 
  router'.
```

And My Code is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";

import App from "./App";
class Home extends Component {
 home = () => {
browserHistory.push("/home");
  };
    state = {};
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.home} className="btn btn-outline-light">
            Logout
          </button>;
 }
```

}

Comment: Which version of React Router? In v4, individual histories were removed and replaced with routers, ie `BrowserRouter` from `"react-router-dom"`

Comment: This may explain everything https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5263

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where's hashHistory in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016415/wheres-hashhistory-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React router not showing browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063229/react-router-not-showing-browser-history)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand your main intention is to change browser URL in the right way, not actually importing a `browserHistory`

For `react-router` v4:

You should benefit here from HOC `withRouter`. Apply it in next manner, and this will pass into your component some additional props that will allow navigation over browser history

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Home extends Component {
   home = () => { 
      // - you can now access this.props.history for navigation
      this.props.history.push("/home");
   };

   render() {
       return ( 
           <button onClick={this.home} className="btn btn-outline-light">
            Logout
          </button>;
       )
}

const HomeWitRouter = withRouter(Home);
```

And with react-router v5 and React Hooks this may look like:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const goHome = () => { 
    history.push("/home");
  };

  return ( 
    <button onClick={goHome} className="btn btn-outline-light">
      Logout
    </button>;
  )
}
```

Comment: i am trying to redirect from one page to another and when i googlr it i found this one browserHistory

Comment: Why you are using this HomWitRouter it gives me warning like this is defined but it's value never used.

Comment: You need to export HomeWithRouter component and use it. Or use it in this file.